# What are the drawbacks of deploying an API to Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

On the 1st of December, 2022 [Firebase announced 2nd Generation Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/12/cloud-functions-firebase-v2).

According to the article, each instance of a 2nd-gen function can handle multiple requests, unlike their predecessors which could handle a single request at a time.

This should lead to fewer cold starts, as stated.

Having this in mind, what would be any potential drawbacks of deploying your REST API to Firebase Cloud Functions?

Comment: What is the REST API being used for or how frequently are the functions invoked? Are they processing a lot of information that a compute instance might be better for? It's hard to tell any drawbacks without knowing your use case.

Comment: Hi does my answer help, let me know if not with follow up questions ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to calculate how many times will the function invoke and your use cases using GCP calculator. Then you can consider following aspects.

While there are many advantages to deploying your REST API to Firebase Cloud Functions, these are the expected drawbacks you should also consider. Although this can change based on your user base and activity on the function.

1. **Cost**: Although Cloud function starts with free tier but the cost can quickly add up if your API seems to have a lot of traffic. In addition to that if you want longer function runtimes and increase network egress then you have to pay for that also. You can check about those [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)
2. **Cold Starts**: 2nd gen functions promise to reduce the cold starts but they can still occur if a function has not been invoked for a period of time. This can lead to slower response times for users who are waiting for the function to spin up.
3. **Limited debugging options**: Although you can debug these functions in StackDriver and Logging, it can be difficult to debug more complex issues.
4. **Scalability**: While Cloud Functions can scale automatically to handle spikes in traffic, there may be some limitations to the amount of concurrent requests that can be handled at once. If your API receives a large amount of traffic, you may need to design your architecture to handle this load efficiently. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances) for more information
5. **Performance**: The 2nd-generation Cloud Functions are designed to handle multiple requests, there may still be some performance limitations compared to a dedicated server or container-based solution. Depending on the complexity of your API and the amount of processing required for each request, your user’s may experience some latency or other performance issues.

Upon all of this you can also check [tips and tricks page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) which explains how to deploy and handle these aspects efficiently.

From my personal opinion I will recommend you to use Firebase functions if your other services are also from firebase itself so that you don’t have to worry about these things.

And if in future you need to deploy a express server hosting for your different tasks then you can use [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework) to achieve that.